# Connect to Server as guest from command line

Tags: finder, command-line, mount, smb

I have a SAMBA share I mount on my Mac from time to time. I do this in Finder with `Go > Connect to Server...`, typing `smb://192.168.1.1` into the Server Address field and pressing Connect. On the authentication dialog I choose to Connect Guest, and finally my remote share is mounted in `/Volumes/<share_name>`. This is great.

Can I achieve all of the above with a single command in Terminal? I tried some variations of the advice [provided here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020610225855377), but there are two things missing:

- how do I instruct `mount` to connect as guest?
- how do I create the `/Volumes/<share_name>` directory on the fly, (so it doesn't have to exist before hand)?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you meant "so it doesn't have to **exist** beforehand" ?

Comment: Also, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/697/115

Comment: @Martín good catch, I fixed the typo. The question you link to doesn't address the "connect as guest" issue, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to mount as "guest", you need to use another command: mount_smbfs

```
mount_smbfs -N //guest@server/share /some/existing/path
```

The "-N" is "don't ask for password" (type man mount_smbfs for more info).

As for the second part of how to create it on the fly (the path), I believe that it's not possible. The *mount* command doesn't create it on the fly and even the man pages mention the "correct" way is to mkdir first then mount.

See the [man page for mount_smbfs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html).

Comment: Thanks for digging up the `-N` argument, that's what I was looking for. The creation/removal of the destination directory I can work around in a script.