# mount afp drive via terminal like staff profile user

Tags: terminal, finder, mount, afp

[I was reading this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107308/mount-shared-drive-via-afp-in-terminal) but the answer is for `root` or `sudo` mode profile.

You can see, using finder, something like:

```
sh-3.2# ls -al /Volumes/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root        wheel    136 Oct 19 02:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root        wheel   1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
drwx------   1 pepito      staff  16384 Oct 19 02:56 HD710A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel      1 Oct 19 02:42 HDD -> /
sh-3.2#
```

unmounting the Drive...

```
sh-3.2# ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel   102 Oct 19 03:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel  1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Oct 19 02:42 HDD -> /
sh-3.2# exit
exit
```

Now from like normal user (non privileged mode).

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/HD710A
mkdir: /Volumes/HD710A: Permission denied
$
```

I'm forced to use `sudo` mode

```
$ sudo mkdir /Volumes/HD710A
Password:
$ ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136 Oct 19 03:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel  1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  2 root  wheel    68 Oct 19 03:16 HD710A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Oct 19 02:42 HDD -> /
$
```

Let's go to mount the drive

```
$ mount -t afp afp://pepito:thepassword@MacBook-Air.local/HD710A /Volumes/HD710A
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 1, errno is 1
$
```

Again forced to use `sudo` mode

```
$ sudo mount -t afp afp://pepito:thepassword@MacBook-Air.local/HD710A /Volumes/HD710A
$ ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136 Oct 19 03:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel  1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
drwx------   1 root  wheel  1316 Oct 19 02:56 HD710A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Oct 19 02:42 HDD -> /
$ umount /Volumes/HD710A
umount: unmount(/Volumes/HD710A): Operation not permitted
$ sudo umount /Volumes/HD710A
$
```

The problem when the drive is mounted like `root` or `sudo` mode the write/read using copy & paste operation are limited from *Finder*.

**How to mount like `staff` mode similar to made for/from *Finder*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo mkdir /Volumes/HD710A
Password:
$ ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136 Oct 19 18:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel  1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  2 root  wheel    68 Oct 19 18:06 HD710A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Oct 19 18:03 HDD -> /
$
```

HERE THE CLUE!!!

```
$ sudo chown pepito:staff /Volumes/HD710A
$
```

Now the results and mount!!!

```
$ ls -al /Volumes/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root        wheel   136 Oct 19 18:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root        wheel  1020 Oct 15 23:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  2 pepito      staff    68 Oct 19 18:06 HD710A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel     1 Oct 19 18:03 HDD -> /
$ mount -t afp afp://pepito:thepassword@MacBook-Air.local/HD710A /Volumes/HD710A
$
```

Comment: This will stop working upon reboot and revert to the original permissions.  This is **by design**.  https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4948585099558912

Comment: @Allan I conscientious of I need apply changes for all reboots.

Answer (score 3):

There's some basic misunderstandings of how things are working, so let's clear them up.

`sudo` isn't a "mode" or a "profile", it's a **command** that allows you to execute a command as another user (See the man page:  [`man sudo`](https://ss64.com/bash/sudo.html))

The command `su` allows you to switch or substitute a user's identity ([`man su`](https://ss64.com/bash/su.html)).  So, think of `sudo` as `su`- get another identity and then `do` something.

Without specifying a user, it defaults to `root`:

`sudo foo` = `sudo -u root foo`.

This is not limited to the `root` user either.  User1 can issue a command as User2:

`$ sudo -u User2 foo`

Now, *Finder* doesn't mount anything, Finder will call a function that mounts your device (technically, there's a "listener" function - automount - that waits for a device to be inserted to automatically mount it).  Finder just "displays" it.

This automounter is running with `root` level privileges which is required to mount *anything* in the `/Volumes` folder which is where automount will put the folder to the newly mounted device.  Users aren't allowed to modify this folder which is why you need `root` privileges; thus `sudo`

If you want to mount something without using `sudo`, mount it anywhere you have full ownership, like in your home directory (`/Users/username/foo/bar`).  Since you have full ownership in that directory, you won't need `root` privileges to mount it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I'm focused in the result and with your help I remember the clue (the `chown` command)!!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going through the low-level process (creating the directory and then using `mount`), just let the OS handle the details for you:

```
open afp://pepito:thepassword@MacBook-Air.local/HD710A
```