# Is it ever possible for a disk/volume to be mounted anywhere other than in /Volumes?

Tags: macos, filesystem, storage, mount, disk-volume

It seems that under macOS that all disks of every type will always be mounted under `/Volumes`. (Except, of course, for the boot drive which will always be mounted at `/`.)

But is this just the case under "normal" circumstances for most people most of the time?

Is it ever possible that some kind of storage could be mounted elsewhere like on other *nix type OSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - use the mount command by hand using a command line shell and terminal application.

- [Here’s how to mount a SMB share manually](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/697/5472).
- [Here’s how to mount a AFP share manually](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107308/5472).

Interrupting a direct attached disk mount is not as easy. *(or documented here yet AFAIK)*

Comment: So is this only applicable to share volumes then?

Comment: Good point @hippietrail - I suppose someone should try to `umount` and `mount` a direct attached disk similar to a network share. I’ve never seen someone interrupt the system mounts, but you probably could redo that with a little effort each time after the system mounts it to /Volumes.