# Mount Error when attempting to mount a network server

Tags: macos, network, mount

I've been attempting to mount a network server on my computer. I can do it through Finder, but this is inconvenient since I can only connect with one username at a time. I read that mounting via Terminal would allow me to connect with multiple usernames at the same time. I found this post: [How can I mount an SMB share from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line/) where the command to mount is

```
mount_smbfs //user@SERVER/folder ./mntpoint
```

but whether I do that or `mount -t smbfs` instead of `mount_smbfs` I get the same error:

```
mount_smbfs: mount error: [mountpoint path]: Input/output error
```

Someone even mentioned getting the same error in that post I linked to above, but no one answered him.

Edit:
For the sake of being complete, here's my actual input and output (with the username and password replaced). I even created a new directory /Volumes/testShare to test it with.

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:Volumes magavendon$ mount -t smbfs //[user]:[password]@172.25.206.80 /Volumes/testShare
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/testShare: Input/output error
```

And the mount_smbfs command:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:Volumes magavendon$ mount_smbfs //[user]:[password]@172.25.206.80 /Volumes/testShare
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/testShare: Input/output error
```

Comment: you did change the ./mntpoint to a valid path, right ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do `mkdir ./mntpoint` first.

For example:

```
mkdir /Volumes/home
mount_smbfs //tom:tomspassword@fileserver/home /Volumes/home
```

Comment: I did already create the directory. I even tried a different directory ./test just in case.

Comment: yes, but try removing the dot. The Dot is translated as "Current Directory". The / is the root directory.
So basics here:
cd /Volumes = Volumes folder in root of HDD;
cd . = Current directory;
cd ./Desktop = Desktop folder in your home folder;
cd ~ = your home folder;

Now if you try to mount a Volumes at ./test it creates the mountpoint in the current dir under currentDir/test.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I guess my previous statement wasn't very clear. I didn't make a directory called ./test just test. I used ./test when passing the directory I wanted to put the mount point in for the mount command.

Answer (score -2):

So, you want to go the hard way, here you go :

```
mkdir /Volumes/[share] | mount_smbfs //[user]:[password]@[server]/[share] /Volumes/[share]
```

BUT:

You can connect multiple times to the same server
with different users via the <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> Box in Finder.

Basically: `smb://user@server` (or SMB1 = `cifs://user@server`).

It automatically adds the a number to every duplicate share that is connected,
so if you have "Data" twice on the server, but for different users, or for same users, but with different priviliges, then Mac creates /Volumes/Data first, then on the second connection creates /Volumes/Data-1.

But this is not visible to the User, you see both as "Data" Sharepoints in Finder.

Comment: I did figure out how to connect this way through Finder.  But when I connect with a different user the data that should be in that user's directory doesn't show up. I was hoping that if I could mount through terminal that might solve my problem.
Furthermore, even if I did get the user's data to show up in Finder when logging in with the correct user I still wouldn't be able to log in with multiple users _at the same time_, which is what I want to do.

Comment: Just to clarify. My problem input/output error isn't that I don't have the directory correctly named or existing. I know how to do that.

Comment: If you've already authenticated with the SMB server as one user, Finder ignores the `user@` part of the URI and just proceeds as the user you've already connected as.