# How can I mount a remote SSH folder on Mac without sshfs?

Tags: homebrew, ssh, mount

In the past I had used sshfs `sshfs user@server:/remote_folder ~/local_mount` and osxfuse (now macfuse).
However, sshfs seems to be [deprecated](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sshfs) and I can't find an alternative.

I tried using `smbfs` but always get a "timed out" error:

```
mount -t smbfs //user@server:/remote_folder ~/local_mount
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Operation timed out
mount: /Users/user/mount failed with 68
```

```
mount_smbfs //user@server:/remote_folder ~/local_mount
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Operation timed out
```

I tried the recommendations from [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129753/mount-error-when-attempting-to-mount-a-network-server), but this also didn't fix my problem.

Comment: sshfs is not the same as smbfs, does the remote server even offer access via Samba?

Comment: I am aware that it is not the same, I am looking for an alternative. On the server I get: ```samba --version >>>Version 4.2.14-Debian```

Comment: Since the remote host is an SMB server, you can use SSH to forward the SMB port to a port on the local host. See: https://rmust.me/how-to-smb-over-ssh

Comment: Is samba just installed or is a samba server running?