# Mounting Samba shares under /Volumes without GUI fluff

Tags: macos, command-line, script, mount, smb

I know I can mount Samba share using either `mount` or `open` command from the terminal shell. See this related question: [How can I mount an SMB share from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line). I prefer using `open` because it mounts the shared folder under `/Volumes` which seems kind of OS X standard, the expected thing. Namely this happens by typing

```
open "smb://guest:@${host}/${path_component}"
```

(where `${host}` is the host name or IP address of the Samba share and `${path_component}` is the path or "name" of the Samba share). 
The result and the main thing is that I can access the stuff from `/Volumes/${path_component}`.
This is very nice indeed. Just there are two problems or nuisance doing this from within scripts. The first is that this will open a superfluous progress indicator and then Finder window. The second, lesser one as there are scriptable work-arounds, is that the command returns immediately without waiting for the mount to be really available.

Is there a way to (synchronously) mount Samba shares under `/Volumes` without extraneous windows popping up?

(I am using the latest OS X (Sierra).)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following is what I use to mount Samba shares via `launchd`:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e "try" -e "mount volume \"smb://guest@${host}\"" -e "end try"
```

Using `osascript`'s `mount` means any `keychain` access needed is done "automagically", there's no progress indicator or Finder window, and the command waits for the mount to be available before proceeding (try it with `&& echo -n "Done."; mount` appended to the end of the above command to test this).

Comment: OSA script? That's some weird stuff, but it works just like I want it to! Thanks!

Comment: @FooF osascript is the command line interface for AppleScript.

Comment: Perfect. For shares needing authentication, you can replace `smb://guest@$host` with `smb://username:password@$host` in the above command.

Comment: Loved this answer, but now...my smb share has changed hosts..how do we update this script?  Plus, not sure if this is standard, but /usr/bin/osascript is currently inaccessible to me for modification...even if I sudo.  This is my work laptop, so it is entirely possible that my employer has locked this down since I first executed this script and I may just have to deal with the error dialog when the mount fails.

Comment: It works, except even when I add password it still asks for one. A window pops open and asks me to enter password

Comment: I tried this and the keychain access part does not seem to work. Just keeps prompting for user details. Initially username root prefilled and asks for password. Using su <username> -c '<commands>' sets the local username instead of root, but the remote needs a different one. then putting smb://username@ solves that part, but still no passwd. Seems kechain is not accessed at all?