# How to open a network share with the "open" command and not create a Finder window?

Tags: network, script, mount, afp

My Mac runs a daily script (via `cron`) that mounts an AFP network share on a remote server, writes to it, and unmounts the share. Unfortunately, the script has a side-effect of opening a Finder window to view the network share, which pops up in the middle of the user's day, interrupting their work. Is there a way to mount the network share without opening the Finder window?

I mount the network share using the `open` command (`/usr/bin/open`):

```
open afp://username:pw@server.com/MyVolumeName
```

I've already tried the `-g` option (*Do not bring the application to the foreground*) and the `-j` option (*Launches the app hidden*) for `open`, but the Finder window still appears.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282770/mounting-samba-shares-under-volumes-without-gui-fluff which addresses the same issue with SMB.

Answer (score 1):

The `open` command, opens the file/folder/share using the default application of the the file/folder/share type.  In this case Finder.

You need the `mount` command. Try:

```
mkdir MyVolumeName
mount_afp afp://username:pw@server.com/MyVolumeName myVolumeName
```

You don't need the `mkdir` if the mount point already exists as an empty folder. But read the documentation first with `man mount_afp`.

Unless you have a reason to use AFP, it is generally better to use SMB using `mount_smbfs`.