# How can I automount a network share on macOS Catalina?

Tags: network, catalina, mount, automount

I want to connect to a network share and I want the connection to remain active after logout. I tried:

```
$ echo "/-      auto_smb        -nosuid,noowners,nofail
        /-      auto_afp        -nobrowse,nosuid" >> /etc/auto_master
$ echo "/System/Volumes/Data/mount/Test2 -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw ://$username:$password@server/share" >> /etc/auto_smb
$ automount -cv
```

My username and password have special characters so I tried escaping them and replacing them with URL encoding, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is the article that i used
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-the-mac-os-x-automounter/
and my code:

```
networkPath
persistent="true"
username
password


function debugEcho () {
  if (true) then
   echo -e $1
  fi
}

shareName=${networkPath##*/}
debugEcho "$shareName"
userPersistent=$username
userPersistent=$(echo "$username" | tr "\\" ";")
if [[ $username == *"@"* ]]; then
  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS=@
  set -- $username
  user=$1
  domain=$2
  debugEcho "$user $domain"
  userPersistent="$domain;$user"
  IFS=$OIFS
  debugEcho "$userPersistent"
fi

username=${username//@/"%40"}
debugEcho $username
shareName="TEST7"

if [[ "$persistent" == "true" ]]; then
  mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/mnt
  LINE="/System/Volumes/Data/mnt/Resources auto_resources"
  FILE='/etc/auto_master'
  grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
  touch /etc/auto_resources
  LINE="$shareName -fstype=smbfs ://$userPersistent:$password@$networkPath"
  FILE='/etc/auto_resources'
  grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
  automount -cv
  open "/System/Volumes/Data/mnt/Resources/"
  path1="/System/Volumes/Data/mnt/Resources/"
  path2="~/Desktop/"
  debugEcho "$path1"
  ln -s $path1 $path2

else
  open "smb://$username:$password@$networkPath"

fi
```

Comment: I don't know about AFP, but I found SMB much simpler than the above: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line/247885#247885

Comment: It would be important to note that AFP's been deprecated for some time now:  https://eclecticlight.co/2019/12/09/can-you-still-use-afp-sharing/. SMB would be a better option.

Comment: this solution is for smb. @WGroleau i tried that solution but the paths are different since Catalina.