# Importing macOS Caching server data from an external Mac caching server

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, data-transfer, internet-sharing

Apple Cache Manager Utility question. We have just bought a second newer Mac mini to act as my school's Primary Apple Caching Server for our ever growing fleet of student iPads (over 500 and counting). I wanted to transfer/import/absorb the Cache from our old (Secondary) server into our new server on the same network...

Wondering if anyone has ever successfully imported a Caching Server's cache from another using the commands provided by Apple in macOS Help?

https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchla6d4541e/mac

I have used variations of this command but have had no success, even when the Volume is mounted remotely using AFP, using the command mount_afp (ref: [How can I mount an SMB share from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line/171822))

```
sudo AssetCacheManagerUtil absorbCacheFrom /Volumes/ServerHD-1/Library/Application\ Support/Apple/AssetCache/Data read-only
```

Would anyone know under what conditions the command from Apple can be used successfully?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is your primary need to cache iCloud data or store and update downloads?

Answer (score 0):

I would just set up the second Mac and let them peer for a while. In the past it was likely to invalidate the entire cache by trying to move it or even restore it from a backup. The new commands you listed are intended to do precisely what you seek.

I’ll update if I test this, but I would assume several things:

- It likely won’t matter if afp or smb shares are used if you try to move content via file sharing. SMB slightly preferred as it’s the new standard.
- I would disable caching services before attempting any utility move.
- I would move the cache to an external drive and then eject / move / absorb it to the new machine. (I almost always store cache on an external drive anyhow)
- We put one cache server on every network segment, three or more on big network segments. With 100 or so, we do as little configuration as possible - no peering or parents have been needed yet.

With two or three caches - they rebalance each other without even needing to set up parent or peering configurations, but if you have massive clients to serve, you can make very sophisticated hierarchies with [parent specific hash settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/content-caching-parents-options-on-mac-mchl4a316675/mac) to maximize cache space or minimize lossage and internet when one node should fail.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-multiple-content-caches-on-mac-mchle150fb54/mac